# CSS3 Rendering Different between browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm a fairly new coder, so I hope this question makes sense.

I am building a website and currently working on the Navigation bar.
As I am building the search bar, using a sprite image I have come across a problem when viewing the site live in different browsers.
the search button image renders differently on safari compared to firefox, chrome, IE and Opera.

`<hgroup>
    <form id=header-search>
        <input class=searchbox placeholder="Search Spout TV"><input type=submit class=button value=""/>
    </form>
    <p class=login><a href="#">LogIn</a><p class=arrow-down></p></p>
    <p class=line>|</p>
    <p class=signup><a href="register.html">Sign Up</a></p>
</hgroup>`

this is the CSS3 code for it:

```
#header-search {
    overflow: visible;
}
input.searchbox {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #af5354;
    border: 1px solid #af5354;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    height: 19px;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.3em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 220px;
}
input.searchbox {
    margin-top: 00.3em;
}
input.searchbox:focus {
    background: #e87476;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e87476 0%, #e87476 20%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e87476), color-stop(20%, #e87476));
    outline: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}
*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #FFF;
}
*:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #FFF;
}
*::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #FFF;
}
*:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #FFF;
}
#header-search input.button {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 -36px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    background: url("../../assets/images/sprite.png") -142px -7px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header-search input.button:hover {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 -36px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url("../../assets/images/sprite.png") -142px -47px;
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The view of html elements is different in each web browser and it's all because each web browser may have different engine. If you would like to have similar display on each web browser maybe you should try use boostrap?
1.You can download it from: http://getbootstrap.com/
2.Next you have to put the file bootstrap.min.css in the location where is your index.html
3.Next include the command

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
```

between

```
<head></head>
```

markers.

The second case- If You use html5 and css3 You don't need to use

```
-webkit-border-radius:
```

Just use:

```
border-radius:
```

For all(actual versions) web browsers it should be ok.

Or maybe I don’t understand your question.. hmm?

Comment: Hello Marcin,
Thank you for that.
If you go to www.spouttv.com/spout/index.html and look at the search button, it renders the same with all browsers except for safari, In safari it puts it down by 1px, where as all the other browsers line up.
Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Maybe try to use <table> out of the
 <form id="header-search">

Comment: of course remember to use also <tr> and <td>  markers inside the <table></table>, maybe it will help hmm..

Comment: I'd like to avoid using tables if possible, and do it using pure css.

Comment: Ok I understood but You can check only this cuz it takes you only few minutes(if You dont mind?); replace your pece of code with this:  <tr>
        <form id="header-search">
            <table>
            <td><input class="searchbox" placeholder="Search Spout TV"></td>
            <td><input class="button" type="submit" value=""></td>
            </table>
        </form>
    </tr>
I'm thinking about another option..

Comment: Maybe @sdcr option is better.. You can use an image to create background in your css file. Do You know how to do this and why?

Comment: Hey Marcin,
Yes I know how to do the background image.
I put it in a table for now.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Whether it works correctly, after you put that piece of code in the table??